# How do I update a variable in a method each time it is called? (JAVA)

Tags: java, javafx, methods

I'm fairly new to coding and i'm wondering if its possible to update a variable each time its method is called. Any help would be appreciated.

Heres what i've got so far (not sure if its correct):

```
public class Score {

    public int score = 0;

}
```

My main class:

```
public void addScore () {
    Score s = new Score();
    s.score++;
    System.out.println(s.score);

}
```

Comment: You are updating a variable.  The problem is that you are creating a `Score` object in the method ... and then implicitly discarding it.  (Or, to put it another way, you are updating the wrong variable!)  You need to create the `Score` object somewhere else, and (somehow) pass the reference to the `Score` object to `addScore`.  But there is not enough context in your question to tell you what the right way to do this is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're creating a brand `new Score` each time the `addScore()` method is called. So that is the `score` that you're updating and not the original `Score` you created.

There are a **lot** of different ways to handle the persistence in this case, but perhaps the easiest would be to create an `addScore()` method within the `Score` class itself:

```
class Score {

    private int score = 0;

    public void addScore() {

        score++;

    }

    public int getScore() {

        return score;
    }
}
```

Then, in your main application, create one `Score` object and call its `addScore()` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Score score = new Score();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            score.addScore();
            System.out.println(score.getScore());
        }
    }

}
```

---

As I said, though, there are several other options, depending on the overall needs of a real-world application.

Another possibility is to create a single `Score` as I do in the `main()` method above and then but pass its reference to the `addScore()` method as a parameter. In order to do that, you'd need to update the method:

```
private void addScore(Score score) {
    score.addScore();
}
```

Then call `addScore(score);` from the main application instead.

---

You can learn more about the issue you're facing by reading up on [the scope of variables in Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp).